# Mapping inherited entities

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Im using Fluent Nhibernate(with pleasure) but have some trouble mapping some entities:

```
  public enum AdverticeType { None,Image,Flash,Script}      

  public class Advertice      
  {
      public virtual int ID { get;set;}
      public virtual string Name { get;set;}
      public virtual AdverticeType AdverticeType  { get;set;}
  }

  public class ImageAdvertice : Advertice
  {
       public virtual int ID { get;set;}
       public virtual string Path { get;set;}
       public virtual string URL { get;set;}
  }

  public class ScriptAdvertice : Advertice
  {
       public virtual int ID { get;set;}
       public virtual string Code { get;set;}
  }
```

How do i map to entities so the ID in ScriptAdvertice is generated by ID in Advertice.

Answer (score 0):

Map `Advertice` using a `ClassMap`, and `ImageAdvertice` and `ScriptAdvertice` using a `SubclassMap`.

e.g.

```
public class AdverticeMap : ClassMap<Advertice>
{
  public AdverticeMap()
  {
    Id(x => x.ID);
  }
}

public class ImageAdverticeMap : SubclassMap<ImageAdvertice>
{
  public ImageAdverticeMap()
  {}
}

public class ScriptAdverticeMap : SubclassMap<ScriptAdvertice>
{
  public ScriptAdverticeMap()
  {}
}
```